# Linear optimization python

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I try to add start up costs to a working scheduling problem (working without start up costs). The schedule should be optimized over a dynamic period, i.e. all 96 quarters of a day. I have a list of 96 prices which I convert to a matrix:

```
prices = np.matrix([prices.as_matrix()])
prices = prices.T
length = prices.size
Range = range(np.size(prices))
```

and following variables:

```
c_turb = -100
min_turb = 0
max_turb = 8
c_pump = -50
min_pump = -10
max_pump = 0
```

This is my objective funtion:

```
 prob = pulp.LpProblem("The PSP",LpMaximize)
 prob +=lpSum([(price[i])*pump[i] for i in RANGE]
             + [price[i]*turbine[i] for i in RANGE]
             + [z_turb[i]*c_turb for i in RANGE]
             + [z_pump[i]*c_pump for i in RANGE])
```

and my variables are defined as the follow:

```
pump = LpVariable.dicts("pump", RANGE,upBound=0,  cat="Integer")
turbine = LpVariable.dicts("turbine", RANGE, lowBound=0, cat="Integer")
pump_status=LpVariable.dicts("pump_status", RANGE,  cat="Binary")
turbine_status=LpVariable.dicts("turbine_status", RANGE,  cat="Binary")
z_pump = LpVariable.dicts("pump_startup", RANGE,  cat="Binary")
z_turb= LpVariable.dicts("turbine_startup", RANGE, cat="Binary")

for i in pump:
     pump[i].lowBound = -10 #bounds can vary for each i but irrelevant for problem

for i in turbine:
     turbine[i].upBound = 8
```

now I added the following constraints:

```
for i in range(1,length+1):
    n=range(0,i)
    prob += lpSum((-0.8*pump[i]-turbine[i])*0.25 for i in n ) <=50        prob += lpSum((-0.8*pump[i]-turbine[i])*0.25 for i in n) >=0
    prob += pump[i]>=min_pump*pump_status[i]
    prob += pump[i]<= max_pump*pump_status[i]
    prob += turbine[i] >= min_turb * turbine_status[i]
    prob += turbine[i] <= max_turb * turbine_status[i]

    if i == 1:
        prob += z_pump[i] == pump_status[i]
    else:
        prob+= z_pump[i]>=pump_status[i]-pump_status[i-1]
        prob+= z_pump[i]<=pump_status[i]
        prob+= z_pump[i]<=(1-pump_status[i-1])

    if i == 1:
        prob += z_turb[i] == pump_status[i]
    else:
        prob+= z_turb[i]>=turbine_status[i]-turbine_status[i-1]
        prob+= z_turb[i]<=turbine_status[i]
        prob+= z_turb[i]<=(1-turbine_status[i-1])
```

where `turbine_status` and `pump_status` should be the on/off status of the turbine/pump in this particular quarter `i`. 
`z_pump` and `z_turb` should store the number of starts, i.e. the switch from the status from 0 to 1.

However, I get an error in line: `prob += pump[i]>=min_pump*pump_status[i]`. Unfortunately the `error info: 96` is not really verbose....

Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Won't `pump[i]>=min_pump*pump_status[i]` be evaluated to `True`  or `False`? Are you trying to add `1` in case it gets evaluated `True`?

Comment: @ klutt: I added some more pieces of the code, example reproduces the error if tested on a random series of prices

Comment: @ narn: with this equations I try to define the pump_status either to 1 or 0. If `pump[i] ==0` then `pump_status =0` or if `pump[i]<0` then `pump_status>0` and as it is a binary variable --> `pump_status =1`